# llnode returns no findjsobjects

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, lldb, coredump

I am in the process of debugging a memory leak in our node application.  I am however unable to use llnode to show any javascript objects.  I've followed Brendan [instructions](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2016-07-13/llnode-nodejs-memory-leak-analysis.html).

I have tested on different versions of Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.04, as well as using node 7 and 8.

I went back and tried a simple [case](https://developer.ibm.com/node/2016/08/15/exploring-node-js-core-dumps-using-the-llnode-plugin-for-lldb/):

```
var http = require('http');
var host = "127.0.0.1"
var port = 1338

server = http.createServer(function myRequestListener(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
  res.not_a_function()
}).listen(port, host);

console.log(`Server process ${process.pid} running at http://${host}:${port}/`);
```

I then would send a seg fault signal (the above code is put into server.js):

```
kill -s SIGSEGV `ps -ax | grep server.js | cut -d " " -f 1 | head -n 1`
```

I then would run:

```
lldb-4.0 -c /cores/core.dump -f /usr/bin/node
```

Inside llnode when I queried for javascript objects I got back and empty list.

```
(lldb) v8 bt
* thread #1: tid = 28763, 0x00007f8947ff7929, name = 'node', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV
  * frame #0: 0x00007f8947ff7929
    frame #1: 0x00005585e8df035b node`v8_inspector::V8FunctionCall::callWithoutExceptionHandling() + 11
    frame #2: 0x00005585e8ddf26c node`v8_inspector::V8Debugger::captureStackTrace(bool) + 92
    frame #3: 0x00005585e8bc1493 node`node::inspector::InspectorSocketServer::SocketConnectedCallback(uv_stream_s*, int) + 163
    frame #4: 0x00005585e8bbb821 node`node::inspector::InspectorConsoleCall(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) + 817
    frame #5: 0x00007f8947f153f1
(lldb) v8 findjsobjects
 Instances  Total Size Name
 ---------- ---------- ----
(lldb)
```

Where I would expect to find javascript objects. I suspect it is a PEBKAC problem, but if anyone has any pointers to where I might have gone astray.

Comment: When did you install llnode and where from? Node 8 support is relatively recent so if you have an old version hanging around you might have problems.
You can install the latest version to test with quickly by doing:
npm install --lldb_exe=lldb-4.0 nodejs/llnode
to install from github and have npm build the plugin library.

Comment: I installed llnode from github about 1-2 weeks ago.  Ive tried different versions of lldb as well, with 3.8 and using LLNODERANGEFILE, but nothing has worked for me.


`lldb-4.0 -c /cores/core.28763.1498757571 -f /usr/bin/node
(lldb) target create "/usr/bin/node" --core "/cores/core.28763.1498757571"
Core file '/cores/core.28763.1498757571' (x86_64) was loaded.
(lldb) v8 findjsobjects
 Instances  Total Size Name
 ---------- ---------- ----
(lldb)`

Comment: As a sanity check was /usr/bin/node the same node executable that ran your program?

Comment: That is correct.  I first tried copying the node binary from elsewhere before I got this issue.  Then I decided to reproduce with no extra variables, everything local, same version of node on the machine.

Comment: This is probably getting too long for the comments, if you raise an issue against [llnode](https://github.com/nodejs/llnode) we can discuss it there and (hopefully) post the fix back here once it's resolved.

Comment: In my case, it caused by not having permission to read the core file.

Answer (score 1):

This is some kind of necroposting, but we had same problem with electron build - `v8 findjsobjects` returns no output.

All things below for MacOS builds.

So, the problem is in 'visibility' linker flag, which is forced to be 'hidden' in electron builds. That's why `v8dbg_` constants, needed for llnode, not attached by linker even with `debug` ninja config, and llonde can't find any objects.

To beat this we forced default visibility with pragma in python-generated debug-output.cc file and finally was able to view js objects. to follow this path append

`#pragma GCC visibility push(default)`

before footer declaration in file `electron-gn/src/v8/tools/gen-postmortem-metadata.py` and rebuild all electron from scratch. Also build can be really huge, make sure you have ~100GB of free space.

I think same thing will works for node/v8 builds alongside electron.

Hope this helps.